# Facebook Application - How do I get the additional information to show a user like

Tags: facebook

I want to post something like this on a user's wall who likes my application:

[image: likes google]

I want the title (linked to the URL) that the user likes and a description right under it. Currently when a user likes my application, only the url gets posted. ex: User likes http://google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lint the URL being liked at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and fix the OG warnings and errors that you have.  Once you've done that, then Facebook is more likely to popup a share dialog with the user and also properly show the values for title, description, image, etc when liked.

Comment: For now I'm getting the image and the title correctly, but don't seem to be able to load the description which is defined with a og:description tag. Not sure if I'm missing anything. I think I should also may be wait for the search index bots to run to be able to see this.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer, all you had to do was to add the metatags provided on the step two: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Once this is done, you'll have to probably wait for a day or two for these to be picked up by the crawlers as meta data. They will automatically be seen on clicking like.

I have removed the metatags, but they continue to be seen. May be they are cached, finding a solution to not show them.